# Can't start activity in addValueEventListener

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to navigate user and admin to different activities. I checked `permission="user"`. While i watch it on debugger `if(permission == "user")` condition doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    itemList.clear();
    String name=dataSnapshot.child(uId).child("name").getValue(String.class);
    String surname=dataSnapshot.child(uId).child("surname").getValue(String.class);
    String phone=dataSnapshot.child(uId).child("phone").getValue(String.class);
    String email=dataSnapshot.child(uId).child("email").getValue(String.class);
    String permission=dataSnapshot.child(uId).child("permission").getValue(String.class);

    itemList.add(name);
    itemList.add(surname);
    itemList.add(phone);
    itemList.add(email);
    itemList.add(permission);
    if(permission == "user"){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,PriceCheckActivity.class));
    }
    else if(permission=="admin"){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddProductActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not test strings for equality using `==`. Use `"user".equals(permission)` instead.

Comment: Unless u r using `kolin` ;) , use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` or `matches`

Comment: Thank you :) Thats work